# I need to pass given credentials with a powershell command

Tags: powershell, user-interface, scripting, credentials

Scenario: my company has beefed up security and has nerfed our local admin rights. we can only use laps. I have a scripe that can get the LAPS password and put it in a textbox. I have several functions that will require the lokadmin user and password. here is one. If i can make this work I can make the rest work. I need to pull the username and password from a textbox. thanks in advance

the username will be the contents of compnameTextbox.text\lokadmin

```
function gpupdate(){
     $User = "$compnameTextbox.text\lokadmin"
     $PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$lokpwdTextbox.text" -AsPlainText -Force
     $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
     $result.text += "`r`n" +  "Applying Group Policy Updates to " + $compnameTextbox.text
     Invoke-GPUpdate -Force -Computer "$compnameTextbox.text" -Target "User" -Credential  $Credential
     Invoke-GPUpdate -Force -Computer "$compnameTextbox.text" -Target "computer" -Credential $Credential
     $result.text += "`r`n" + $compnameTextbox.text + " Policy Updates in Progress"
     $Comp = $compnameTextbox.Text
  }
```

Comment: Get-Credential : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: I have already tried that method. didn't work

Comment: I will edit my original post to show what I have tried.

Comment: What error are you getting?   Which command?  Try using single quotes instead of double quotes so backslash doesn't get substituted. Also type $Credential to see if it is null.

Comment: One thing to note in your script is that interpolation won't work properly for object properties when written like this: `"$compnameTextbox.text\lokadmin"`.  Using a sub-expression should get you the correct information: `"$($compnameTextbox.text)\lokadmin"`.